# Create secret for gcp service account for helm

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets

I am trying to authenticate to the GCP account when I deploy velero to the cluster, Is there any way I can create the secret of the below content and pass it to helm rather then passing all the variable in this yaml file?

```
credentials:
  useSecret: true
  secretContents:
    cloud: |
      {
        "type": "service_account",
        "project_id": "",
        "private_key_id": "",
        "private_key": "",
        "client_email": "",
        "client_id": "",
        "auth_uri": "",
        "token_uri": "",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "",
        "client_x509_cert_url": ""
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can set [existingSecret](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/helm-charts/blob/velero-2.23.12/charts/velero/values.yaml#L278) to the name of a Secret you have already created in your cluster.  The Secret would contain a single key named `cloud` with the value set to the content of the appropriate credentials file.

I would be remiss if I did not note that the more secure way to do this would be to enable [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) for your GKE cluster and then [bind the Velero Kubernetes ServiceAccount](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero-plugin-for-gcp/blob/v1.3.0/README.md#option-2-set-permissions-with-using-workload-identity-optional) to the GCP service account.